# Determining amount of change in correlated variables

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

Say I have 3 independent variables (x1..x3), all highly correlated with a dependent (Y). I'm looking to determine if x1 changes by a certain amount, how much Y would expected to change. Also, looking to say if x1 AND x2 change by a certain amount, how much Y would expect to change.

Would covariance assist with doing this? Appreciate any insight or point in right direction!

Edit: I've done separate linear regression to determine correlation of x1 to Y, x2 to Y, x3 to Y (have not done a multivariate to determine combination of those 3 to Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform multiple regression with X1, X2, and X3 as predictors for Y.  Regression weights for X1...X3 are B1...B3.  B1 indicates the expected increase in Y for each 1 unit increase in X1. B2 represents the incremental change in Y for X2, and so on.

In terms of change based on more than one X at a time, lets say that you're interested in C1 change in X1 and C2 change in X2.  You'd predict that Y would change by (C1*B1) + (C2*B2).  This answer assumes that all of your X variables are linearly related to Y and that there are no significant interaction terms.